# Pixate Freestyle real time css

Tags: ios, pixate

I have not found any reference of how to get real time css updates using Pixate Freestyle and Xcode 5.  If someone could provide the code for what goes into 'didFinishLaunchingWithOptions' in the AppDelegate that would be helpful.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an older question/answer you can use as reference: [How to get Pixate v2 Real Time CSS working with Xcode 5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20526864/how-to-get-pixate-v2-real-time-css-working-with-xcode-5)

Note that Freestyle has renamed the base object from Pixate to PixateFreestyle.

Comment: I was just about to post this same answer. :)

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Paul.  Using that post I was able to get it working.  Here is the code that I put in my AppDelegate.m file.

## import "AppDelegate.h"

## import "PixateFreestyle/PixateFreestyle.h"

@implementation AppDelegate

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:     (NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    //Initalize Pixate
    self.window.styleMode = PXStylingNormal;
    //Dynamically modify the Pixate stylesheet while the Simulator is running
    #ifdef DEBUG
    [PixateFreestyle styleSheetFromFilePath:@"/path/to/project/default.css" withOrigin:PXStylesheetOriginApplication];
    PixateFreestyle.currentApplicationStylesheet.monitorChanges = YES;
    #endif
    return TRUE;
}
```